# ggplot2 pie plot with geom_text_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, ggrepel

I am plotting multiple pie plots with ggplot2 and succeeded in having the labels plotted in the right positions, as:

```
df <- data.frame(annotation=rep(c("promoter", "intergenic", "intragene", "5prime", "3prime"), 3), value=c(69.5, 16, 10.7, 2.5, 1.3, 57.2, 18.8, 20.2, 2.1, 1.7, 50.2, 32.2, 15.3, 1.2, 1.1), treatment=rep(c("treated1", "treated2", "untreated"), c(5, 5, 5)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = annotation)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
coord_polar(theta = "y") +
facet_grid(.~treatment)
```

I then wanted to make use of ggrepel so that the small slices numbers do not overlap:

```
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = annotation)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text_repel(aes(label = value), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +  
coord_polar(theta = "y") +
facet_grid(.~treatment)
```

But I get the following warning
"Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: position"

and messed up labels.

Anyone knows how to combine the right positioning of the labels with geom_text_repel, or any alternative?

Thank you!

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux 7.2 (Nitrogen)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggrepel_0.6.5 ggplot2_2.2.1 limma_3.26.9 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      digest_0.6.12    grid_3.3.2       plyr_1.8.4      
 [5] gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.4.1     stringi_1.1.5   
 [9] reshape2_1.4.2   lazyeval_0.2.0   labeling_0.3     tools_3.3.2     
 [13] stringr_1.2.0    munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to make a correct column with position of your labels before `coord_polar()`. I would do it with 'dplyr' but you can use whatever you comfortable with:

```
library('dplyr')

df <- df %>% 
  arrange(treatment, desc(annotation)) %>% 
  group_by(treatment) %>% 
  mutate(text_y = cumsum(value) - value/2)

df
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 15 x 4
> # Groups:   treatment [3]
>    annotation value treatment text_y
>         <chr> <dbl>     <chr>  <dbl>
>  1   promoter  69.5  treated1  34.75
>  2  intragene  10.7  treated1  74.85
>  3 intergenic  16.0  treated1  88.20
>  4     5prime   2.5  treated1  97.45
>  5     3prime   1.3  treated1  99.35
>  6   promoter  57.2  treated2  28.60
>  7  intragene  20.2  treated2  67.30
>  8 intergenic  18.8  treated2  86.80
>  9     5prime   2.1  treated2  97.25
> 10     3prime   1.7  treated2  99.15
> 11   promoter  50.2 untreated  25.10
> 12  intragene  15.3 untreated  57.85
> 13 intergenic  32.2 untreated  81.60
> 14     5prime   1.2 untreated  98.30
> 15     3prime   1.1 untreated  99.45
> ```

Now text and labels will be in the middle of a column when we will use `text_y` as a `y` aesthetic for `geom_text()`.

Plot prior to `coord_polar()`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = annotation)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_label(aes(label = value, y = text_y)) +
  facet_grid(.~treatment)
```

[image: Bar plot]

And now adding `label_repel` and transforming coordinates:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = "", y = value, fill = annotation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label = value, y = text_y)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ treatment) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

[image: Polar_pie]

Comment: Thank you! It works very well. I am curious about something: can I force geom_label_repel to write the labels outside of the pie plot itself, so as to keep it a bit more clean?

Comment: @sargg You can use `geom_label_repel(aes(label = value, y = text_y), nudge_x = 1.6)` or use some other value.